# WCF send info from service to client when event happens in service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service

I'm trying to build basic prototypes from a project that will take form a little later down the road.

For this prototype I currently have a console application hosting WCF services and another console application consuming the WCF services.

I have read of the three different message patterns for WCF and from what I understand I can either :

1)Call the WCF service and wait for the answer, locking the consumer while its waiting for the answer.

2)Call the WCF service asynchronously, which doesn't lock the consumer while its waiting for the answer. An answer event will eventually happen.

3)Call the WCF service without expecting and answer at all.

What I would like to know is if it is possible to use WCF to send a message to the client when an event is triggered on the service side. For example if a variable changes on the application hosting my services, a message would be sent to a client.

The only way I can imagine this would be to have my client also host WCF services and send a one way message from my initial host as the client.

This seems like a somewhat odd way of doing things for some reason and I would love to know if anybody has another idea on how this could be done.

Thanks a lot!

Note: Just in case anybody gets stuck on that, I am not looking for a way to trigger events when a variable changes. Also, there is no code in the question because it is mostly an architectural question. If you can point me towards the right tools to achieve what I'm looking for I'm sure i'll find plenty of code examples on how to use them!

Comment: See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @KarelTamayo First, thanks for the link! What I'm noticing is that the callback is always called in result of a request from the client. Would I be able to call these without it being the result of a request? I guess I would have to keep tab of the opened sessions some way to call the callback specific to a session.

Comment: no problem. I'm affraid you're right. You'll need to keep your handles in order to be able to invoke the callbacks.